# Conditional Operators, Validation Issue

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing a *method* that will do a couple of things:

- *Verify the Operating System Version*.
- *Verify the Operating System Platform*.
- *Verify the Account isn't null*.
- *Verify the Account is in the proper role*.

Now, if I implement the traditional *nested if* it works.  Absolutely zero problems- However, for the sake of what I believe to be a *cleaner implementation* has turned into a lovely error.

The syntax:

```
bool result = false;

WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

result = ((Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && 
     Environment.OSVersion .Version.Major > 6 
     && role != null && role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) 
     ? true : false);
```

But I receive the following *exceptions*.

> Operator `&&` cannot be applied to the operands of type
>   `System.PlatformID` and `bool`.

I'm really not sure why it doesn't work, it should.  Am I implementing logic incorrectly or what, I'm really at a loss.

This syntax does work, but when I convert it to the above *Conditional* it doesn't.

```
if(Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion
    .Version.Major > 6)
{
     WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
     WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

     if(role != null)
     {

          if(role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
          { 
               return true;
          }
     }
     return false;
}
return false;
```

---

**Update:**

This is where the red squiggle appears and Visual Studio gave the above mentioned error:

```
PlatformID.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6
```

Comment: Does this work? `(Environment.OSVersion.Platform == Platform.Win32NT) && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6 && role != null && role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)`

Comment: You have a parenthesis that is not closed, is it like that in your code?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Actually no, I don't.  It is closed in my actual code- My apologies for the error.

Comment: I don't see how that code can generate that type error. Can you identify the *exact expression* which causes it? It should also have a "red squiggle" under it. In any case, the type error should be clear: `expr_of_PlatformId && expr_of_boolean` is invalid. Then it's just a matter of finding out what results in `expr_of_PlatformId` and fixing it .. (Hint: look for usages of `=` where `==` is desired.)

Comment: For the update: `PlatformId.Win32NT` *doesn't* evaluate to a boolean. Fix it - by adding an appropriate comparison - so that it looks like the working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional could be rewritten like this:

```
bool result = Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT &&
              Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6 &&
              role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

Note that you can skip the 'role' null check, since it's never null in your case.

**EDIT**

As far as your update goes, the problem is this part:

```
bool result = PlatformID.Win32NT; // <-- this part can't compile, it's not a boolean
```

I believe what you meant to write is:

```
bool result = Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT; // along with your other conditions
```

**EDIT 2**

Since you've asked why doesn't your sample work (not sure what typo you have or what exactly is going on), but this code compiles as well (**NOTE:** *I wouldn't write it like that*, just saying):

```
bool result = ((Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT &&
                Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6
                && role != null && role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
                    ? true
                    : false));
```

Comment: That is the odd part it is indeed written with a comparative value, as noted in my example above.  But the squiggly line appears under it still.

Comment: @Greg What you have is: `PlatformId.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6` where it should be `Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6`

Comment: I was just showing the part that was highlighted by the line reads: `Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6` sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Greg Also, it's not PlatformId it's PlatformID, not sure if typo

Comment: Yeah, typo on my part.

Comment: @Greg If you copy-paste the code that I've given, does it compile ? Or you're still getting the error ?

Comment: Thanks that solved it. Why wouldn't you write it like that and how would you?

Comment: @Greg Glad I could help :) I would write it the first way that I've shown, since it's much more readable, clean and it removes a lot of the redundant checks, with the added bonus of being shorter, and it has the exact same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to use a conditional operator—in fact `… ? true : false` never has any effect at all.

Try rewriting your code like this:

```
bool result = 
    (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT) && 
    (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6) &&
    (role != null) && 
    (role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator));
```

Comment: Are you saying to create it as a long variable, then simply test the variable rather then the above conditional approach?  So it would be two separate lines, result defined- then the conditional test on result?

Comment: No `result` is a `bool`. There's no `long` involved

Comment: There's no need for a conditional test.  It's already a boolean!  However, I would omit the parenthesis on the 4th term here, it's already a boolean, there's no point in wrapping a single item.

Comment: @LorenPechtel True, I just wrapped each term for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

**Not tested , you can try**

```
   bool result = false;

    WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

    result = (((Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT) && 
         (Environment.OSVersion .Version.Major > 6) 
         && (role != null) && ((role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) 
         )? true : false))));

    return result;
```